# how to disable row-selection of datatable in primefaces

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatables

I am using Primefaces 4.0,
I am having a datatable with multiple selection features.What Im willing to achieve is to select the rows only by the checkbox button, disabling capability of clicking a row. IN present scenario my checkbox is selected even if i click on any row, I want to disable row-selected.

```
<p:dataTable id="tradingTable" scrollable="true"
                resizableColumns="true" draggableColumns="true"  scrollWidth="1265"
                scrollHeight="650" var="pgers"
                selection="#{pager.selectedPageArray}"
                value="#{pager.pageDataModel}"
                sortMode="multiple"
                editable="true" editMode="cell" 
                rowSelectMode="add"     

                >  
                <p:column width="30" selectionMode="multiple"   >
                </p:column>
```

I got some solution from [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31035) forum but  unable to resolved it. Please suggest me what needed to be done.

Answer (score 9):

**Although your question is about Primefaces 4.0, I thought it would be useful to highlight that this problem is now solved in newer versions. It may be useful to someone else.**

According to this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7103), this feature is now supported in Primefaces versions **5.0.3** & **5.1** by simply adding rowSelectMode="checkbox" to the datatable.

Documentation reference (PF 5.1):

> Use rowSelectMode option to customize the default behavior on row
>   click of a multiple selection enabled datatable. Default value is
>   "new" that clears previous selections, "add" mode keeps previous
>   selections same as selecting a row with mouse click when metakey is on
>   and "checkbox" mode allows row selection with checkboxes only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.5, but I think the same workaround should be applicable.
What I did to disable the row selection is to [remove the selected row immediately with the rowSelect event by adding <p:ajax /> component in the datatable](http://www.kianworknotes.com/2014/10/how-to-disable-row-selection-in.html).

It might not a good solution, but at least it works.